# Is it possible to pass data as part of NSNotifications?

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller

*Scenario, in context of a card game:*

User moves a card on the screen. As a result of a move, coordinates of the card change. If card is found to be in some specific location, we'd like to make sure Card object (Model) is updated to include those coordinates.

But View should not be talking to the Model directly .., so

Instead of updating Card directly, View is going to notify its Controller that "Card has landed". Upon receiving this notification, i'd like for a Controller to update Card's location instead of the View (Controller updates Model)

**Question 1:**
Am i thinking about this type of scenario correctly?

**Question 2:**
Is it possible to send data to a controller along with a notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `NSNotifications` for your scenario: a straightforward delegate-based approach should do.

The view should *define* a delegate interface, and provide a non-retaining `delegate` property. The controller should *implement* the delegate interface, and set itself as view's delegate. The view would then notify its delegate without even knowing that it notifies the controller. The controller would then pass the notification along to the model.

```
@protocol CardDelegate
-(void)cardHasLanded:(SOCard*)card atPosition:(SOPosition*)pos;
@end

@interface MyView
@property (weak, nonatomic,readwrite) id<CardDelegate> delegate;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
-(id)init { // This should be in your designated initializer
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        MyView *view = [[MyView alloc] init];
        view.delegate = self;
        self.view = view;
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)cardHasLanded:(SOCard*)card atPosition:(SOPosition*)pos {
    // Update the model
}
@end

@implementation MyView
@synthesize delegate;
-(void) doSomething {
    // ...
    if (cardHasLanded) {
        [delegate cardHasLanded:card atPosition:pos];
    }
    // ... more code
}
@end
```

Comment: Excellent response. Thank you

Comment: In your example, is it needed for the controller to implement the Protocol? Does not look like it, but i'd like to make sure

Comment: While the delegate approach also is a standard design pattern and surely very useful here, the notification approach has the advantage that it's easy to have new observers respond to the action. For example, an object that wants to do some statistics simply can observe the notification as well, no changes needed on the sender side. With the delegate pattern it wouldn't be so easy and likely to generate tighter coupling. One would need to change it to a listener pattern instead to keep up the loose coupling.

Comment: Thank you for your insights DarkDust. Just got an idea from your comment. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

That's what the `userInfo` dictionary and `object` of `NSNotification` are used for. In this case, it's the `object` you want. For example:

```
// In your model header file

extern NSString * const CardMovedNotification;

// In your model implementation file

NSString * const CardMovedNotification = @"CardMoved";

...

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CardMovedNotification object:theCardThatMoved];
```

Your obversers then can get the card via `[notification object]`. If you need to pass more information, you'd create a dictionary and pass that as `userInfo`, via `postNotificationName:object:userInfo:`. The observer then can query it via `[notification userInfo]`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that no notifications are needed. Usually for UI object coordinates I won't use a model object because the coordinates are coupled to the UI object (or else where will you draw it ?). What you do need to do is register your controller to the touch end event passing in the UI object where the touch was made and updating (in the responding controller method) the object's coordinates if they indeed within the desired location. (as done with buttons and other UI objects)